# Multilingual comments in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, comments

I set up an English/Arabic Drupal 8 website.
However, comments are misbehaving.
When a user enters a comment in the English version of the article, it appears in the Arabic version, and vice versa.
I went through all the different options I can think of, but I ended up with all comments being treated and displayed as Arabic.
I don't know what I'm missing, or what how I am supposed to configure it.

Shouldn't it respect languages out of the box?

Please, any help or documentation would be greatly useful. Thanx

Answer (score 3):

At this moment in my team, we have identified 3 bugs around this, and to make this works you need to apply this 3 patches:

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2751269#comment-12559117

https://www.drupal.org/comment/12521645#comment-12521645

https://www.drupal.org/comment/12561153#comment-12561153

Comment: Thank you very much, but the patches end result was not to misredirect the commenter after submission. But still the comments appear in both languages